How to determine which Profiles have access to an External Credential Named Principal
Under the new Named Credentials model, access is granted to the underlying External Credential using Named Principals; as of API 59.0 these can be granted to Profiles or Permission Sets.  The Metadata API includes these Principals in the PermissionSet object using the PermissionSetExternalCredentialPrincipalAccess type.  But there doesn't appear to be an analogous type available in the Profile object.  Short of checking each profile one at a time in the UI, is there any way to enumerate all profiles which have access to a given External Credential Named Principal?

SetupEntityAccess stores this information by filtering SetupEntityType = 'ExternalCredentialParameter'.
Unfortunately, querying this object does not allow to traverse External Credential fields to filter by label or developer name.
So if you need to filter for a specific External Credential, capture the Id in the URL from the related list "Enabled External Credential Principal Access" of a known profile which has this credential then use the Id to filter on SetupEntityId.
Alternatively, you can query for the External Credential Principal Id using this Tooling API query:
SELECT Id, ExternalCredential.DeveloperName, parameterName 
  FROM ExternalCredentialParameter 
 WHERE ParameterType = 'NamedPrincipal'

Query both for profile and permission set:
SELECT Parent.IsOwnedByProfile, Parent.Profile.Name, Parent.name, SetupEntityType,SetupEntityId
FROM SetupEntityAccess 
WHERE SetupEntityType = 'ExternalCredentialParameter' 
and SetupEntityId = '0puQy0000001lcn'

(in above parent.name gives permission set name)
Query for profile only:
SELECT Parent.Profile.Name, SetupEntityType,SetupEntityId 
FROM SetupEntityAccess 
WHERE SetupEntityType = 'ExternalCredentialParameter' 
AND Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = TRUE
and SetupEntityId = '0puQy0000001lcn'

Query for permission set only:
SELECT Parent.name, SetupEntityType,SetupEntityId
FROM SetupEntityAccess 
WHERE SetupEntityType = 'ExternalCredentialParameter' 
AND Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = FALSE
and SetupEntityId = '0puQy0000001lcn'

If you need to check profile and/or permission set for legacy Named Credential access, then filter SetupEntityType = 'NamedCredential' and change SetupEntityId accordingly
More info on SetupEntityAccess

Thanks, this is great.  With some tinkering, I found a way to discover the Principal Ids via Tooling API query, which I added to your answer.

Ah cool, thanks
